# Python: Use of dict derived class - strange behavior of self={

Tags: python, class, dictionary, self

What is the difference between class A and class B?

What's wrong with self?

Why do I need to declare self line by line?

```
class A(dict):
  def __init__(self):
    self={1:"you", 2:"and me"}
    print "inside of class A",self
class B(dict):
  def __init__(self):
    self[1]="you"
    self[2]="and me"
    print "inside of class B",self

a=A()
print "outside of class A",a
b=B()
print "outside of class B",b
```

**result:**

```
inside of class A {1: 'you', 2: 'and me'}
outside of class A {}
inside of class B {1: 'you', 2: 'and me'}
outside of class B {1: 'you', 2: 'and me'}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  def __init__(self):
    self={1:"you", 2:"and me"}
```

This doesn't modify the object passed as `self`, but re-binds the local variable `self` to a new dict.

Comment: @pst: what's wrong with "reference"? all values in Python are references

Comment: @newacct The issue I have is that it is an overloaded and somewhat vague term in programming. Thus I prefer to avoid the usage as much as possible, especially when there is no need as shown in this answer.

Comment: An obvious problem with *reference* is that C++ has used it for ages for the kind of object references where an assignment like the above **would** carry the intended meaning.

Comment: @newacct I'd rather word that as "all variables in Python are references to values". And yeah, C++ references are immutable but the real funny part in it is the whole "value types" thing. C++ is the only OO language I know where `A=B;` in object context means "let object A become just like B value-wise", not "let variable A refer to object B". The former is seldomly useful when doing OO and auto-generated operator= makes things even more confusing.

Answer (score 4):

As others said, assigning to `self` is useless because it only changes the value of the local variable without affecting the dict that is being constructed. What you want is something like:

```
self.update({1:"you", 2:"and me"})
```

or even:

```
dict.__init__(self, {1:"you", 2:"and me"})
```

If you really want to have control over *which* instance your class constructor returns (for example, to implement instance caching), [look up `__new__`](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__).

Comment: awesome way to play with python language: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 2):

In class A, you are assigning to the local `self` variable.  When `__init__` is called, `self` contains a reference so the constructed object.  You are reassigning it to something else completely; *this does not change the instance of class A at all*.

In fact, if you define a new method on class A you will notice that the dict you've assigned to `self` isn't even visible there.  It became unreferenced the moment `__init__` returned.

Answer (score 0):

just adding to the other good answers. you can see the difference in the Byte-code:

**Byte-code of `A`:**

```
Disassembly of __init__:
  3           0 BUILD_MAP                2
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('you')
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              9 STORE_MAP           
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('and me')
             13 LOAD_CONST               4 (2)
             16 STORE_MAP           
             17 STORE_FAST               0 (self)  # stores values in local variable
                                                   # i.e not changing the object at all

  4          20 LOAD_CONST               5 ('inside of class A')
             23 PRINT_ITEM          
             24 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             27 PRINT_ITEM          
             28 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE        

None
```

**Byte-code of `B`:**

```
Disassembly of __init__:
  8           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('you')
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)  #loads self, i.e instance of dict
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              9 STORE_SUBSCR                       #store value in it   

  9          10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('and me')
             13 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             16 LOAD_CONST               4 (2)
             19 STORE_SUBSCR        

 10          20 LOAD_CONST               5 ('inside of class B')
             23 PRINT_ITEM          
             24 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             27 PRINT_ITEM          
             28 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE        

None
```